# Why does Chrome incorrectly compose the URLs for my JSF page's resources?

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

Please have a look at the two screenshots below which show my jsf page (http://localhost:8080//dmeScripts/Test.xhtml) on the left and the browser's developer tools on the right. The first screen shot is of Safari - my page is rendered correctly. The second screenshot is of Chrome - my page is incorrectly rendered.

In the Chrome screenshot the console is reporting errors regarding resources that cannot be loaded - notice that I have selected the components.js.xhtml script and that it cannot be displayed. Contrast this with the Safari screenshot wherein components.js.xhtml is successfully displayed.

Right clicking on components.js.xhtml to obtain the link address I get:

1. Safari -  http://localhost:8080/dmeScripts/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1
2. Chrome - http://dmescripts/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1

In Chrome the link is incorrect. Chrome has "filtered out" the host and port, i.e. localhost:8080. Can anyone tell me how to address this?

**Safari**
[image: Safari]

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]

Comment: Debug the actual initial http response. What is in there. If it is alright there, PrimeFaces and JSF cannot do much about it. Checked if you are by accident running some sort of plugin in the browser?

Comment: And what about the plain jsf ajax javascript? Does **that** get correctly loaded?

Comment: As @Kukeltje mentions, check that your Chrome browser is sanitized. Is it free of controversial plugins and is it the cache cleaned? You could also make a test with more browsers, a Chrome browser in other machine.. and so on.